# Getting content from iframe in Javascript used as form target fails

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, target

I am trying in Javascript to get the inner HTML from an iframe. It has no 'src' attribute but receives the results of a form, like this:

```
<iframe id="randomchallenge" name="randomchallenge" width=300px height=300px ></iframe>
<form name='challenge' method='POST' target='randomchallenge' action='[my URL]'>
[my inputs]
</form>
```

Now this statement should work:

```
var challengetext =  document.getElementById('randomchallenge').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

but I don't get any contents here, although on the page you can see that the iframe is filled with a long string.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: can you provide a codepen ?

Comment: To fill an iframe you need to submit a form first.

Comment: Yes, I have submitted the form. The form results are viewable on the page.

Comment: Is the content in the iframe coming from the same domain as the main page is?

Comment: Yes, the iframe content is from the same domain

Comment: I guess you're reading the content too early, at that point the content is not loaded yet. Try to load the content in `load` handler of `iframe`.

Comment: I'm sure the content is already there. The user pushes a button after visually inspecting the loaded data and then my javascript code starts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a codepen. What's the idea of that?

Comment: After some more testing, the problem seems to be that the database can only be accessed from the main domain whereas the website is on a subdomain. So ... same main domain but different subdomain seems to count as different domains. Not sure how I can solve this.

Comment: Problem solved. If I used the mysqli statements from php instead of the mysql statements, I can access the database from each subdomain, so the iframe will have the same subdomain as the main page.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. If I used the mysqli statements from php instead of the mysql statements, I can access the database from each subdomain, so the iframe will have the same subdomain as the main page.